# Open program as root, close root session but still program is running

Tags: process, users, session

When I run my backup script, first I switch to root, mount a truecrypt partition and then run the script.

I've noticed that after run truecrypt as root, I can exit the root session and truecrypt remains opened.

Why does it happen? Shouldn't it close as long as I close root session?

The commands order is:

`su`

`truecrypt &`

I mount the hidden volume using Truecrypt's UI

`./Backup.sh`

and then the usual is unmount the Truecrypt's volume, close Truecrypt, exit root session. However, if I only close root session Truecrypt keeps running with root permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background processes get *upgraded* to parent process of (on Linux usually) `init`, PID `1`.

> *obviously the & is for run it on background. The question is why it keep running if it was launched by root but root is no longer active?*

`root` is active as long as your system is up running. (`root` as in *the* superuser.)

Anyhow, it doesn't have anything to do with the `root` user per se. As
the process you started is not dependent on the terminal, (or the like),
ending the parent process would not terminate the child. It usually become orphan for a short while then adopted by `init`.

A lot of your processes are run under other accounts. Try e.g.:

```
ps aux | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | sort -u
```

---

To illustrate one can instead use another account, e.g. `testuser`.

`sleeplong`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 9999
```

Save and `cmod +x sleeplong`. Run under `testuser`:

```
user@host $ su testuser
testuser@host $ ./sleeplong &
[1] 9692
```

Open `top` with PIDs:

```
user@host $ pids="$(pstree -cpsa 9692 | \
sed 's/ *[^,]*,\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | tr '\n' ',')"; \
top -w 90 -p ${pids}1
```

Enter <kbd>V</kbd> to get tree

```
  PID USER         TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root        0:01.03 init
19787 user       95:30.58  `- terminal
 8835 user        0:00.16      `- bash
 9634 testuser    0:00.04          `- su
 9642 testuser    0:00.09              `- bash
 9692 testuser    0:00.00                  `- sleeplong
 9693 testuser    0:00.00                      `- sleep
```

Exit:

```
testuser@host $ exit
```

Run top routine again:

```
  PID USER       TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      0:01.03 init
 9692 testuser  0:00.00  `- sleeplong
 9693 testuser  0:00.00      `- sleep
```

---

You can visualize this further by doing something like this:

1. Expand the script to:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sleep 8888 &
   sleep 9999
   ecode=$?

   printf "Bye\n"

   exit $ecode
   ```
2. Run it `./sleeplong2 &` (`su` or not).
3. Start `top` with same routine as above and enter <kbd>c</kbd> to show arguments.
4. In other terminal:

   ```
   kill NNN # Where NNN=PID of sleep 8888
   kill NNN # Where NNN=PID of sleep 9999
   ```

Exit code from last `kill` should normally be `143`. That is

```
128 + 15 = 143
```

As `kill` defaults to 15, or `SIGTERM`.

---

Another thing to try out could be to kill bash (or the like) where `sleep`
reside.

---

Also not that you can do e.g.:

```
$ su testuser -c './sleeplong &'
```

---

Hope it became a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's the & sign after the truecrypt command. This is causing the truecrypt session to run in the background.  if you remove the & symbol it will close when the terminal window is closed.

If you'd like to keep the &, you can use the `fg` command to bring the session to the foreground, after which it should close with the window. Use `jobs` to list all of the jobs in the background if you have more than one.

Comment: obviously the & is for run it on background. The question is why it keep running if it was launched by root but root is no longer active?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

Closing a session doesn't close all of the user's programs. This is by design. For one thing, the user could have programs running in other sessions. The user could also have wanted to keep a program running in the background while he isn't logged in on any terminal (`screen` or `tmux` is especially popular for this).

What closing a session does is roughly speaking to remove the outlet through which programs can interact with the user: in a text mode session, the programs are told that the terminal has disappeared ([SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP)); in a GUI session, the programs are told that the [X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) has gone away. Most programs exit in such circumstances.

Truecrypt arranges to keep running because that's usually the desirable behavior. The Truecrypt process has no way to know whether other processes are using the filesystem, so it keeps running until the filesystem is explicitly unmounted. That's a very common use case: log in to mount an encrypted volume, log out, let other users or automated jobs use the encrypted volume.

Logging out isn't going to magically change which user a process is running as. What would it be supposed to change to anyway?

When you've finished using a filesystem, you need to unmount it. That goes for any filesystem, not just Truecrypt. Once you've unmounted all the Truecrypt filesystems, you can kill the Truecrypt process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this from work, but does the truecrypt process start as a daemon process anyway?
By which I mean, is the init process with pid 1 the parent process of the truecrypt process?

If it is, then it won't terminate if you exit your root shell, because it doesn't get the SIGHUP signal from logging out.